# Import class from a manually created jar file

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a Scala project that is being managed by SBT.  I also have 2 manually created jar files that I need to access for some API calls.  I have created the "lib" folder and placed the two jar files inside of that "lib" folder as per the sbt documentation for unmanaged libraries.  I have also added the jar files to intelli-j's list of libraries.

I am able to do both a clean and compile without error.  However, when I attempt to run the build, I receive errors that the calls cannot be found.

I was able to successfully run the project when it was just a folder of all the classes and java files.

Am I importing the classes from the jar wrong?  Could I have created the jar incorrectly?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you supply the error message you are receving? Perhaps you need to add the JAR to the Project?

Comment: `/Users/admin/Documents/workspace/package/module/src/main/scala/Poller.scala:143: not found: type StringCustomFieldRef
[error]           val cust = record.getCustomFieldList.getCustomField.get(j).asInstanceOf[StringCustomFieldRef]`  

  
  
Is what I'm getting.  It is similar for each of the calls, about two dozen in total.  I've added the jar to lib directory in the parent project.  SBT also indicated that it "sees" the two jar files.

Comment: have you try removing all generated files (normally all files inside *all* `target` directories) and build the project from scratch?